# Simple gallery with CSS problem with displaying in block

Tags: css, layout

So i came up with this code :

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.img
{
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #0000ff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
div.img img
{
  display: inline;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
div.img a:hover img {border: 1px solid #0000ff; width:auto; height:auto}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="a"><img src="images/p1.jpg" alt="a" width="110" height="90" /></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="b"><img src="images/p2.jpg" alt="b" width="110" height="90" /></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="c"><img src="images/p3.jpg" alt="c" width="110" height="90" /></a>
</div>
<div class="img">
 <a target="_blank" href="d"><img src="images/p4.jpg" alt="d" width="110" height="90" /></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My goal was to make a simple gallery where the image is enlarged when the mouse is on it, it's all ok, but now I want to make exact dimension - I mean a box with lets say 600x300px cause now it takes the whole monitor, I guess I need to adjust the CSS but dunno how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to wrap your images in a container div, do this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="img">
       ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 #container { width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; }
```

This will give you a nice box with scrolling, having the specified dimensions. If you do not need scrolling and a fixed height, don't specify height and use `overflow: hidden` which is needed because the elements inside are floating (this will let the container take up the occupied space of the floating divs).

Comment: Sorry, I'll make myself clear - if I have 10 images they will take the whole width of the page, I want to make it so that in a row you can have max 4 images.I think it's best to warp the gallery in some box, but don't know how to do it...

Comment: @Leron Edited my answer based on what you wrote.

Comment: Yes but what happen is that the first picture is shown enlarged with scroll, the second covers the 3rd and 4rth and I cant enlarge the 3rd and 4th at all...

Comment: @Leron Would you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I have to go now, I'll accept your answer and try to do the remaining by myself.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’m not exactly sure what you’re asking, but does the following code do what you want?

```
div.img a:hover img {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    width:600px;
    height:300px
}
```